# Edittext and images in gridview

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-gridview

Hello and greetings i am developing one app that accept multiple images from user and upload to server but images upload to server is ok.I just added one `edittext` to enter quantity of image but i am unable to get value from that respective edittext.so give me suggestion in my code.

i have `edittext` in `gridview` so i want to get text from edittext that is quantity of image so please help me

uploadphoto.java

```
    public class UploadPhotos extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context context;
    SelectPaper paperSession;
    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    SelectLab labSession;
    SessionManager session;
    String strSize,strType,str_username,strMRP,strPrice,strlab,strcity,strdel_type;
    MaterialEditText ppr_size,ppr_type,mrp,disPrice;
    SelectedAdapter_Test selectedAdapter;
    long totalprice=0;
    int i=0;
    String imageName,user_mail,total;
    GridView UploadGallery;
    Handler handler;
    ArrayList<CustomGallery> listOfPhotos;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    String Send[];
    Snackbar snackbar;

    Button btnGalleryPickup, btnUpload;
    TextView noImage;
    String abc;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_photos);
        context = this;

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

        final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        assert ab != null;
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id
                .main_content);
        labSession = new SelectLab(getApplicationContext());
        paperSession = new SelectPaper(getApplicationContext());
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
        user_mail = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_EMAIL);

        noImage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.noImage);

        final String symbol = getResources().getString(R.string.rupee_symbol);


        HashMap<String, String> paper = paperSession.getPaperDetails();
        strSize = paper.get(SelectPaper.KEY_SIZE);
        strType = paper.get(SelectPaper.KEY_TYPE);
        strdel_type=paper.get(SelectPaper.DEL_TYPE);

        HashMap<String, String> lab = labSession.getLabDetails();
        strMRP = lab.get(SelectLab.KEY_MRP);
        strPrice = lab.get(SelectLab.KEY_PRICE);
        strlab = lab.get(SelectLab.KEY_LAB);
        strcity = lab.get(SelectLab.KEY_CITY);
        str_username=lab.get(SelectLab.KEY_USERNAME);



        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+strSize+"\n"+strType+"\n"+strMRP+"\n"+strPrice+"\n"+strlab+"\n"+strcity,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        ppr_size = (MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.paper_size);
        ppr_type = (MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.paper_type);
        mrp = (MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.MRP);
        disPrice = (MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.discount_price);

        ppr_size.setText(strSize);
        ppr_type.setText(strType);
        mrp.setText(symbol + " " + strMRP);
        disPrice.setText(symbol + " " + strPrice);

        initImageLoader();
        init();


    }

    private void initImageLoader() {
        DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheOnDisc().imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
        ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder builder = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                this).defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions).memoryCache(
                new WeakMemoryCache());

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = builder.build();
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(config);
    }

    private void init() {

        handler = new Handler();
        UploadGallery = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.uploadGallery);
        UploadGallery.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        selectedAdapter = new SelectedAdapter_Test(getApplicationContext(), imageLoader);
        UploadGallery.setAdapter(selectedAdapter);
        btnGalleryPickup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);
        btnGalleryPickup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Action.ACTION_MULTIPLE_PICK);
                startActivityForResult(i, 200);
            }
        });

        btnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_upload);
        btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listOfPhotos = selectedAdapter.getAll();
                if (listOfPhotos != null && listOfPhotos.size() > 0) {
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
                    abc = sdf.format(new Date());
                    abc="EPP"+abc;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+abc,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    //progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadPhotos.this, "", "Uploading files to server.....", false);
                    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(UploadPhotos.this);
                     progressDialog.setMessage("Images is Uploading.......");
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    progressDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mp3));
                    progressDialog.show();
                    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            doFileUpload();
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                                        totalprice=0;
                                    }
                                    Intent i=new  Intent(UploadPhotos.this,Digital_Cart.class);
                                    startActivity(i);


                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    thread.start();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please select two files to upload.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }



    });



        UploadGallery.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                CustomGallery objDetails = (CustomGallery) selectedAdapter.getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position : " + position + " Path : " + objDetails.sdcardPath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 selectedAdapter.changeSelection(view, position);
            }
        });
    }

    private void doFileUpload() {
        for( i = 0 ; i<listOfPhotos.size();i++) {
            final CustomGallery objDetails = (CustomGallery) selectedAdapter.getItem(i);
            File f = new File(objDetails.sdcardPath);
             imageName = f.getName();

             totalprice=totalprice+Long.parseLong(strPrice);
            total=String.valueOf(totalprice);
            Log.v("Abhijit",""+totalprice);


            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+totalprice,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String responseString = null;

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://eeee.com/aaaaa/UploadFile?foldername="+abc);     //TODO - to hit URL);
            try {
                AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                        new AndroidMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void transferred(long num) {
                             //   publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                            }
                        });

                File sourceFile = new File(listOfPhotos.get(i).sdcardPath);
                // Adding file data to http body
                entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));
                entity.addPart("foldername", new StringBody(abc));

                entity.addPart("size",
                        new StringBody(strSize));
                Log.v("svbh", strSize);
                entity.addPart("type",
                        new StringBody(strType));
                entity.addPart("username",
                        new StringBody(user_mail));
                entity.addPart("total",
                        new StringBody(total));
                entity.addPart("mrp",
                        new StringBody(strMRP));
                entity.addPart("price",
                        new StringBody(strPrice));
                entity.addPart("lab",
                        new StringBody(strlab));
                entity.addPart("city",
                        new StringBody(strcity));
                entity.addPart("imagename",
                        new StringBody(imageName));
                entity.addPart("deltype",
                        new StringBody(strdel_type));
                String initflag=String.valueOf(i+1);
                entity.addPart("initflag",
                        new StringBody(initflag));
                entity.addPart("lab_username",
                        new StringBody(str_username));
                //  totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
                httppost.setEntity(entity);
                // Making server call
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
                final String response_str = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
                if (r_entity != null) {

                    Log.i("RESPONSE", response_str + "" + imageName);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                  snackbar = Snackbar
                                        .make(coordinatorLayout, i+" image "+response_str, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                            snackbar.dismiss();
                                            }
                                        });

                                // Changing message text color
                                snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.RED);

                                // Changing action button text color
                                View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                                TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                                textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);

                                snackbar.show();


                                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),i+" image "+response_str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            }


        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 200 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            String[] all_path = data.getStringArrayExtra("all_path");
            noImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            UploadGallery.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ArrayList<CustomGallery> dataT = new ArrayList<CustomGallery>();

            for (String string : all_path) {
                CustomGallery item = new CustomGallery();
                item.sdcardPath = string;
                dataT.add(item);
            }

            Log.d("DATAt",dataT.toString());
            selectedAdapter.addAll(dataT);
        }
    }

  
}



and selected_adapter_test

    public class SelectedAdapter_Test extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<CustomGallery> data = new ArrayList<CustomGallery>();
    ImageLoader imageLoader;

    private boolean isActionMultiplePick;


    public SelectedAdapter_Test(Context c, ImageLoader imageLoader) {
        mContext = c;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.imageLoader = imageLoader;
        // clearCache();
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imgQueue;
        ImageView imgEdit;
        EditText qty;
        Button ok;


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return data.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    public void changeSelection(View v, int position) {

        if (data.get(position).isSeleted) {
            data.get(position).isSeleted = false;
            ((ViewHolder) v.getTag()).imgEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ((ViewHolder) v.getTag()).qty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ((ViewHolder) v.getTag()).ok.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            data.get(position).isSeleted = true;
            ((ViewHolder) v.getTag()).qty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((ViewHolder) v.getTag()).ok.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((ViewHolder) v.getTag()).imgEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflate_photo_upload, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imgQueue = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgQueue);
            holder.imgEdit = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgedit);
            holder.qty = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            holder.ok = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);

            holder.imgEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.qty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.ok.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            holder.ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    data.get(i).qty= 1;

                }
            });

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        //holder.imgQueue.setTag(position);


        imageLoader.displayImage("file://" + data.get(i).sdcardPath, holder.imgQueue, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                holder.imgQueue.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_media);
                super.onLoadingStarted(imageUri, view);
            }
        });

        if (isActionMultiplePick) {
            holder.imgEdit.setSelected(data.get(i).isSeleted);
            holder.qty.setSelected(data.get(i).isSeleted);
            holder.ok.setSelected(data.get(i).isSeleted);
            Log.d("Position Data", data.get(i).toString());
            Log.d("Position", String.valueOf(i));
        }

                return convertView;
    }


    public void addAll(ArrayList<CustomGallery> files) {

        try {
            this.data.clear();
            this.data.addAll(files);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public ArrayList getAll(){

        return data;
    }

}
```

And customGallery.java

```
  public class CustomGallery {

    public String sdcardPath;
    public int qty;
    EditText aaa;
    public boolean isSeleted;
}
```

so please help to get text from edittext that is quantity.i cant figure out the problem from last one week.

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you also give your resource files.

Comment: you can save your edittext value in your data object CustomGallery on textChangeListner.

Comment: how to do that.... could you please explain me how to save edittext value in  data object CustomGallery on textChangeListne

Comment: sir can you make changes in my code  to save value in data

Answer (score 0):

Here is  the code :

```
@Override
public View getView(final int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflate_photo_upload, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imgQueue = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgQueue);
        holder.imgEdit = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgedit);
        holder.qty = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        holder.ok = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);

        holder.imgEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.qty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.ok.setVisibility(View.GONE);

holder.qty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // save your text here
  data.get(i).qty= 1;
            }
        });



        holder.ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                data.get(i).qty= 1;

            }
        });

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    //holder.imgQueue.setTag(position);


    imageLoader.displayImage("file://" + data.get(i).sdcardPath, holder.imgQueue, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            holder.imgQueue.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_media);
            super.onLoadingStarted(imageUri, view);
        }
    });

    if (isActionMultiplePick) {
        holder.imgEdit.setSelected(data.get(i).isSeleted);
        holder.qty.setSelected(data.get(i).isSeleted);
        holder.ok.setSelected(data.get(i).isSeleted);
        Log.d("Position Data", data.get(i).toString());
        Log.d("Position", String.valueOf(i));
    }

            return convertView;
}
```

Comment: i am not getting sir please tell me to how to store value in data that is customgallery

Comment: data.get(i).qty= holder.imgEdit.getText().toString()  is not working

Comment: then you can get your editext value in Activity as adapter.getAll()

Comment: sir just make changes in my code i am totally confussed because i am trying to fix bug from last week so now my mind is not working properly

Comment: bhai tughe saturday toh nahi bolata?

Comment: i want dynamic value not default 1